# Calling a method in a different solution

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Currently I have a solution whose hierarchy looks like this.

```
-GUI
 -ENTITIES
 -DATA
 -BLL
  -ENTITIES
  -DATA
   -ENTITIES
```

1) Is that the right way to lay it out. I'm removing the DATA reference from GUI currently (just legacy code that I'm moving to the BLL)

2) Is there any way for ENTITIES to call a method from the BLL or DATA? Like in Entities.Order have Order.GetNextOrderID() that calls a method from DATA?

Comment: There is no "right way" to layout a solution. Only the way that makes sense for the project. Its your project.. so you need to make sense of the layout. As for your second question - its hard to say without seeing a proper graph of your dependencies.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Xx9Fquj.png thats what I got from View Project Dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is that the right way to lay it out. I'm removing the DATA
>   reference from GUI currently (just legacy code that I'm moving to the
>   BLL)

This is an extended subject and it is scenario dependant.

Picture a sistem with componentization, integration with other systems and protocols, native code, multiple client protocols, mobile, test, etc. There would be a lot of layers and multiple Solutions would be needed. Same principle apply for different platforms.

There are a lot of criteria you would have to consider, so the answer is: it depends.

But I guess for what you are doing it fits well.

> 2) Is there any way for ENTITIES to call a method from the BLL or
>   DATA? Like in Entities.Order have Order.GetNextOrderID() that calls a
>   method from DATA?

No, you will get cyclic dependency error. A single module would do it tho, but I wouldnt recommend it.

Also, if you are going to define validation in the entities, make sure your design will not allow for duplication in services (bll) or data. This can go out of control if you do not have a good team or pair revision etc.

The main purpose of the layers is to give it specific responsabilites. If you have well defined responsabilities to your layers you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I will re-iterate my comment for question 1.

> Is that the right way to lay it out.

The "right way" is project dependant.

> Is there any way for ENTITIES to call a method from the BLL or DATA? Like in Entities.Order have Order.GetNextOrderID() that calls a method from DATA?

Not with your current setup.. you'll get a circular dependency. You've become confused between a more DDD-approach (which is what you're going for.. nice!) and an Anaemic Domain Model where the logic sits outside of the entities.

You should choose where the bulk of your logic will sit and work from there. For the DDD approach you're asking about, the Entities project will contain 90% of your logic, and it will have a dependency on the "BLL" project for any other "services" the entities may require.

The flipside for the Anaemic Domain Model is that you have a service in the BLL that loads everything it needs and does all of the operations *in the actual service*. Your entities then become nothing more than POCOs.

Comment: So really to "fix" this issue, I should ?merge? most of the Entities and Data layer if I continue using the DDD approach?

Comment: Don't merge the Entities and Data layers. The entities are persistance ignorant. Your UI can have a "Service" layer that it uses to interact with the database.. but once it has those entities it should defer all logic to them. Then have another "BLL" assembly for any other non-entity-specific logic.

Answer (score 0):

Well a good design would be to keep the Data layer separate from both the GUI and BLL. So that each layer can perform a single task i.e GUI should only concern about the User Interface, controls and views. Business Logic Layer should only implement the Business rules and data layer should interact with your database. For your second question all you need to do is add a reference of your Data project to Entity project. Hope it helps you.

Comment: When I try to add it, I get A reference to 'Data' could not be added. Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency. I understand what the error means, but if I remove Entities from Data, that I can't save the entities.

Comment: Ya the problem then is that you might already have added the reference of 'Entities' to 'Data'. Which is wrong, if you need them to interact with each other than put them in the same project. Layering is done in a unidirectional way. Upper layer can access the lower layer not vice-versa.